# How can I add granular event registration to an invoice for multiple participants?

Tags: civievent, registration, invoice

I'm running CiviCRM 5.13 with Wordpress, and the site is doing very well, but we have some end users who are complaining that the event invoice doesn't show enough detail.

Here's our dilemma:

- The confirmation email has all of the detail that they need, but the users complain that it's too many pages.
- The users are 3rd party association management firms. They need to be reimbursed for the registrations by the associations they manage.
- The invoice provides a billing total but does not list all of the enrolled participants (yes, it's in the confirmation email).
- I see that I can add a token to the invoice, but I suspect that will only capture the person registering the users (not necessarily an attendee).
- As a stop gap, I can probably manage a custom report, but that only makes work for my client.

Does anyone have an invoicing solution to list multiple 3rd party registrations? I've seen activity reports with up to a dozen participants.